# Setting Root Folder in ASP.NET Web App

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I have an ASP.NET web app project in Visual Studio 2015, using IIS Express. The simplified folder structure of the project looks like this:

```
ProjectName
   |
   |
   +--privateFolder
   |
   |
   +--publicFolder
             |
             |
             + -- default.htm
```

Basically, I want the "publicFolder" to be the root of my web application. I have been partially successful at making this happen by editing the applicationhost.config file so that it has this entry (note the "\public" at the end):

```
<virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\Users\blahBlah\Desktop\Dev\Sites\Web Sites\ProjectName\public" />
```

With the above entry in applicationhost.config, the "public" folder is the root of my web application and I am able to browse to a URL like http://localhost:3487 and it serves `Default.htm`, as I want. Note that I do not have to put "/public" in the URL because it is mapped to in the virtualDirectory entry shown above.

My goal then, is to not have "**/public**" in the URL but yet to maintain the directory structure shown above.

Here's the problem though: When I close and then re-start Visual Studio, it re-writes the `virtualDirectory` entry above, removing the trailing "**\public**".

Is there a way to tell VS that I want a particular sub-folder in the project to always serve as the root of the application?

Comment: Why don't you put the contents of the private folder to another project in the same solution or even to a subfolder in the same project but mark it to not to be published with the application?

Comment: @Wiktor - What I showed is a simplified structure. Everything in privateFolder belongs with this project but none of it is served as a resource.

I am looking for a solution to the problem I described, not alternatives to circumvent the problem.

Comment: If you set the `applicationHost.config` file to Read-only, it should preserve settings. Also look at toggling the "Apply server settings to all users" checkbox.